# Why my Android Home Screen App Widget is not working properly?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-appwidget

I'm working on a home Screen Widget for a Chat App. I've created a **[Widget Provider](https://github.com/Redjack1888/AND_Capstone_Project2_MyChatApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/alessandro/mychatapp/widget/MyChatAppWidget.java)** and a **[WidgetConfigurationActivity](https://github.com/Redjack1888/AND_Capstone_Project2_MyChatApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/alessandro/mychatapp/widget/MyChatAppWidgetConfigureActivity.java)**.
When I create an Home widget the configuration show all the available chat for the logged user and when one is selected the widget should appear as an image of the other chat user. A **PendingIntent** then should open the correct **ChatActivity**. 
To do that I need of 3 string values that i can recover from my **Firebase Database**:

- ImageThumb - the url of the Firebase Storage Image
- ChatterUserName - the name of the other chatter
- list_user_id - the Uid of the chatter to retrive the messages from
  Database

Here is **[my GitHub repo](https://github.com/Redjack1888/AND_Capstone_Project2_MyChatApp)**

I save 1 String as **SharedPref** and 2 with [**Paper Library**](https://github.com/pilgr/Paper).

**When I create the first widget all works fine.**

I Retrieve all the strings, create the right **RemoteView** and intent open the right chat with right data.

**The problem occur when I create a second widget.**

The Image of the second widget is right but when I click on it it open the ChatActivity for the first widget.

I've logged to see if all data are retrieved in the correct way

```
08-14 04:37:07.899 27778-27778/com.example.alessandro.mychatapp D/Constraints: onUpdate: appWidgetId: 331, listUserId: kcL4c30lnjhU36TBqhgJQox4dVk1, userName: Dj Maru, userThumb: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mychatapp-8a476.appspot.com/o/profile_images%2Fthumbs%2FkcL4c30lnjhU36TBqhgJQox4dVk1.jpg?alt=media&token=9a748bfe-1f39-44fa-9c29-38d5e60aaa86
08-14 04:37:07.910 27778-27778/com.example.alessandro.mychatapp D/Constraints: updateAppWidget: appWidgetId: 331, user_id: kcL4c30lnjhU36TBqhgJQox4dVk1, userName: Dj Maru, image: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mychatapp-8a476.appspot.com/o/profile_images%2Fthumbs%2FkcL4c30lnjhU36TBqhgJQox4dVk1.jpg?alt=media&token=9a748bfe-1f39-44fa-9c29-38d5e60aaa86
08-14 04:37:07.917 27778-27778/com.example.alessandro.mychatapp D/Constraints: onUpdate: appWidgetId: 332, listUserId: 9saSiY1WT0PNt6derLMsGBcZvJh2, userName: redjack, userThumb: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mychatapp-8a476.appspot.com/o/profile_images%2Fthumbs%2F9saSiY1WT0PNt6derLMsGBcZvJh2.jpg?alt=media&token=28d1b36c-6c43-454e-9ecd-cafca9cee994
08-14 04:37:07.920 27778-27778/com.example.alessandro.mychatapp D/Constraints: updateAppWidget: appWidgetId: 332, user_id: 9saSiY1WT0PNt6derLMsGBcZvJh2, userName: redjack, image: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mychatapp-8a476.appspot.com/o/profile_images%2Fthumbs%2F9saSiY1WT0PNt6derLMsGBcZvJh2.jpg?alt=media&token=28d1b36c-6c43-454e-9ecd-cafca9cee994
```

I've checked also the **mAppWidgedId** values in WidgetConfigurationActivity to be sure that a new Id was created with the new widget.

Then, **if I turn off or restart my device the first widget stop to work… and the second one works fine**.

Someone can help me to understand what is wrong in my code and how to fix it? Thanks a lot.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setOnClickPendingIntent, you have to use views.setPendingIntentTemplate(...) in the provider, and then to have an unique onclick behavior for each of your items in the widget, then you have to set a fillInIntent for each items in the adapter where you populate each item.

Here is link from Google Developers: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets

If you have other questions, please, feel free to ask me :)

Best regards,
László